# Timed out error, for python function, in codingbat

Tags: python-3.x

Q- "We want to make a row of bricks that is goal inches long. We have a number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each). Return True if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the given bricks. This is a little harder than it looks and can be done without any loops."

I started learning Python...I write this code for above problem, but it shows "Timed out" in Codingbat, but when I run this code in Python IDLE for all test cases, it works Perfectly.  Then why does it show "Timed out" error in codingbat?

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):  
    for i in range(big+1):    
        b=i*5    
        for j in range(small+1):      
            if b+j==goal:        
                return True  
    return False
```

Comment: "when i run this code in Python IDLE for all test cases it works Perfectly" - did you try `make_bricks(100000, 100000, 100000000000000000000)`? Coding sites that go out of their way to say "this can be done without any loops" will often actively seek examples that will disqualify you if you use brute force.

Comment: Hint: start by laying out all the small bricks you have. Take away up to four small bricks to make the difference to the goal is divisible by `5` (e.g. if the goal is `17`, and you have nine small bricks, take away two of them, so that `17 - (9 - 2)` is `10`, which is divisible by `5`). If you have one big brick for every five inches the small bricks are still short of the goal, then you can do it. No loops.

Comment: "....without loop" yes u r right, how i forgot that... silly mistake ok now i get this THANK YOU